# android pushnitification expire device registration after 1 week

Tags: android

im implement push notificaitron in my appplicaiton using this tutorial http://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-push-notifications-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-php-and-mysql/ when register device with gcm server  it say registration id expire after 1 week? so what does is mean?device again register ?im using client and server base application sent device id to server and server sent notification client using gcm service. what is parse notification?which is best parse or gcm???

```
      Setting registeredOnServer status as true until 2013-10-07 11:57:35.013


  09-30 11:57:32.223: V/GCMBroadcastReceiver(308): onReceive:          
    com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION

  09-30 11:57:32.223: V/GCMBroadcastReceiver(308): GCM IntentService class:  
 com.schoollunchapp.GCMIntentService
 09-30 11:57:32.243: V/GCMBaseIntentService(308): Acquiring wakelock
 09-30 11:57:32.303: V/GCMBaseIntentService(308): Intent service name: GCMIntentService- 
 747495904150-2
  09-30 11:57:32.348: D/GCMBaseIntentService(308): handleRegistration: registrationId =     
 APA91bFZ4MnFAHChUsAiYLHl4Pw8gSH7FL41kFdAW2qx8ymtKdnyKQ1QlEHeFejVgDtAWTlrvx-jgfFFdZWGLg1D4- 
 iOS1OYkydMKNPRDXC80e63SS-ARmwr7zjqgqW0kshqG7WeOEnCwwYzohbnNUij21K5BnuodA, error = null,   
 unregistered = null
  09-30 11:57:32.348: D/GCMRegistrar(308): resetting backoff for com.schoollunchapp
   09-30 11:57:32.383: V/GCMRegistrar(308): Saving regId on app version 1
  09-30 11:57:32.403: I/GCMIntentService(308): Device registered: regId =  
   APA91bFZ4MnFAHChUsAiYLHl4Pw8gSH7FL41kFdAW2qx8ymtKdnyKQ1QlEHeFejVgDtAWTlrvx-jgfFFdZWGLg1D4-
   iOS1OYkydMKNPRDXC80e63SS-ARmwr7zjqgqW0kshqG7WeOEnCwwYzohbnNUij21K5BnuodA
  09-30 11:57:32.413: I/School Lunch(308): registering device (regId =   
  APA91bFZ4MnFAHChUsAiYLHl4Pw8gSH7FL41kFdAW2qx8ymtKdnyKQ1QlEHeFejVgDtAWTlrvx-jgfFFdZWGLg1D4-  
 iOS1OYkydMKNPRDXC80e63SS-ARmwr7zjqgqW0kshqG7WeOEnCwwYzohbnNUij21K5BnuodA)
 09-30 11:57:32.443: D/School Lunch(308): Attempt #1 to register
 09-30 11:57:32.464: V/School Lunch(308): Posting  
'regId=APA91bFZ4MnFAHChUsAiYLHl4Pw8gSH7FL41kFdAW2qx8ymtKdnyKQ1QlEHeFejVgDtAWTlrvx- 
 jgfFFdZWGLg1D4-iOS1OYkydMKNPRDXC80e63SS-ARmwr7zjqgqW0kshqG7WeOEnCwwYzohbnNUij21K5BnuodA' to  
 http://198.57.208.716/~school/nazeer/nazeer2/register.php
09-30 11:57:32.464: E/URL(308): > http://198.57.208.716/~school/nazeer/nazeer2/register.php
09-30 11:57:32.944: I/global(308): Default buffer sizeused in BufferedReader constructor. It    
  would be better to be explicit if an 8k-char buffer is required.
09-30 11:57:35.013: V/GCMRegistrar(308): Setting registeredOnServer status as true until  
 2013-10-07 11:57:35.013
 09-30 11:57:35.056: V/GCMBaseIntentService(308): Releasing wakelock
09-30 11:57:41.313: V/GCMBroadcastReceiver(308): onReceive:  
com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE
09-30 11:57:41.313: V/GCMBroadcastReceiver(308): GCM IntentService class:   

 com.schoollunchapp.GCMIntentService
 09-30 11:57:41.313: V/GCMBaseIntentService(308): Acquiring wakelock
  09-30 11:57:41.364: V/GCMBaseIntentService(308): Intent service name: GCMIntentService- 
747495904150-3
```

Comment: which notification is best parse or gcm???

Comment: I never heard of "parse notifications"

Comment: check this https://parse.com/apps/quickstart_push#android/native/existing